# How to write data into a text file using Java and not let it overwrite previous input. Basically how to get each record in next line?

Tags: java

Basically I need to Write the data i take input into a file, but create a new record each time. My function overwrites the previously inputted line. So i always have just one record. I tried using WriteLine() but it doesn't help and shows error
I also want to know how to really write one thing in one line and the next input in next line.
Please help.

```
   public static void addworker()
        {
            Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter ID:");
            String I = S.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Username");
            String user = S.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Password:");
            String P = S.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Type: ");
            String T = S.nextLine();
            System.out.println(" Salary:");
            String Sal = S.nextLine();

            try
            {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("input.txt");
            BufferedWriter fb = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            fb.write(I, 0, I.length());
            //fb.writeLine();
            fb.write( user, 0, user.length());
            //fb.writeLine();
            fb.write(P, 0, P.length());
            fb.write(T,0, T.length());
            fb.write(Sal,0, Sal.length());
            fb.close();
            fw.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to append  a file using

```
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("input.txt",true);
```

The `true` parameter is set a append mode to your file

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Comment: Yes i understand, but im not sure with my whole implementation, it always overwrites the previous record, I guess Im not storing it properly?

Comment: The code is and working properly .just set a parameter true and set 
            fb.newLine(); and run it